# How to set filename* in content disposition of FormData using javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http-headers, multipartform-data, form-data

Using FormData.append(), is it possible to append a Blob data and set *RFC 5987* `filename*` directive in the [content-disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Directives)?
(Note: this is not `filename`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Our server API is checking this value and I haven't found a way to set it from the client side.

Comment: So your server isn't able to recognize UTF-8 in default `filename`? Interesting, never fell on such an issue.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss here, [RFC 7578](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578#section-4.2) states: *"NOTE: The encoding method described in [RFC5987], which would add "`filename*`" parameter to the Content-Disposition header field, MUST NOT be used."* They also say a bit above that filenames "MAY" be percent-encoded, though testing rapidly on my system, it doesn't get decoded... From the above, I'd say having UTF-8 for form-data's sub-part's header is perfectly ok, and should be handled by your server. Can you tell us a bit more about it?